# Black dash / line on visual studio 2012 left margin

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I google this , But didn't find the explanation for this.
can someone help me explain what the black dash / line means?

thank you

[image]

Comment: You don't have to edit your question to include the answer. That's what the _answer_ is for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I searched for the same thing, but stumbled upon it by accident.  When you do a search on your code the 'Find Results' box appears.  Highlight a line in the Find Results box and the black dash appears in the indicator margin next to the corresponding line of code in which the results were found.

Answer (score 0):

It also appears when you double-click on an error in the error list (I'm using MSVS 2019 C++ project).