# What is the black flag icon in gutter of VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, icons

Visual studios 2013 is showing a black flag looking icon in the left gutter of my code. It doesn't seem to have any meaning and there is nothing particularly special about that line of code. The code works fine, I just want to know why this icon is displayed and what it means.

Comment: I saw this also. I frequently format my code by pressing ctrl+k, ctrl+d and a bookmark is set with very close command: ctrl+k, ctrl+k

Answer (score 30):

It may be bookmark or it may be *the line at which searched text is found*. In this screenshot, the black mark at line 55 shows the line in which search text is found(when we search using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keys) and one at line 58 is bookmark.

Bookmark can be removed by holding holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing <kbd>K</kbd> twice. There is also option to remove it in VS menu, same icon as on the line.

Bookmarks are put on the code where we want to navigate more frequently. There is icon in VS menu shown with the arrow and bookmark icon to move forward and backward.

[image]

Answer (score 27):

It could be a bookmark. See main Visual Studio menu Edit - Bookmarks.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using dark theme this is a white flag. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> removes the flag.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on the answer given by @Imad. The icon at line 55 can be the result of a search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). You remove it by either clearing or closing the Find Results pane.

*Or* it might be an error indicator from the most recent compilation. These appear in the Error List pane. Fix and recompile to remove it.

Line 58 shows a bookmark. Remove it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on the line in question.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a Search in VS using Ctrl+shift+F -> Find all  -> click on a result from the find results tab -> you can see the black pin pointing the matching line in the code.

The answer is here - [Black dash / line on visual studio 2012 left margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702611/black-dash-line-on-visual-studio-2012-left-margin)